# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n^p)+5}{n^2}$ and find $p$

Tags: calculus

Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n^p)+5}{n^2}$ converges for which $p \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm starting to think it's every value of p converges because it's sin function. I can compare to $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ and it converges everytime.

Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^p +1}}{n^4}$ converge for what values of $p \in \mathbb{R}$? i think it's squareroot function, so $n^p$ is slow to increase, and we can compare it to $\sum \frac{1}{n^4}$, but it's might grow so fast and it diverges. So finally I think for values $p < 6$ it converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It converges absolutely because $|\sin(n^p) + 5| \leq 6$ and $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {6 \over n^2}$ converges (and in fact equals $\pi^2$).

We derive that $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {6 \over n^2}$ converges by the fact that $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {1 \over n^k}$ converges if and only if $k > 1$.

If we consider your second problem of $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {\sqrt{n^p + 1} \over n^4}$, we see that ${\sqrt{n^p + 1} \over n^4}$ ~ ${1 \over n^{4 - {p \over 2}}}$. And therefore, this sum converges iff $4 - {p \over 2} > 1$; that is, iff $p < 6$.